# 5 V encoder output to 3.3V micro

Tags: stm32, interface

I need to interface a 5V digital output from an encoder(https://media.futek.com/content/futek/files/pdf/productdrawings/trs605.pdf) with a STM32F411 (https://www.dfrobot.com/product-2338.html). What kind of components do I need to level shift this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Simple resistor divider should be enough.

Comment: That was my plan. But my mentor insists that I use a level shifter.

Comment: Most of the GPIO pins are 5V tolerant by design. So you don't need to worry about that, if you can convince your mentor. I have quoted datasheets in my answer.

Comment: Do you you need the torque signal or just the encoder?

Comment: I need both torque and encoder. I already have a circuit for torque signal, but not sure if it's correct or not yet.

Answer (score 2):

Most of STM32's GPIO pins are 5V tolerant. You can check from Tables 7 and 8 in the [product specifications document](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f411cc.pdf) for your STM32F411CC. The [reference manual](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f411cc.html)  says on page 155 "In the analog configuration, the I/O pins cannot be 5 Volt tolerant."

So as long as the encoder signal is connected to a GPIO pin (other than PA0, PB5) that is configured as a digital input, you don't need any extra components.

Comment: Does that mean I can connect directly using a cable?

Comment: Yes. You can connect using a jumper cable.